# Java (Android) Insert icon on canvas

Tags: java, android, image, canvas, resize

So i have custom View, where i draw on canvas. I would like to add icon or some image on canvas. I tried with

```
canvas.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name)
```

The probleme here is that my icon is resized to fit the screen and i have no control to resize or scale image.

Maybe i can get height and width of canvas, and then create Drawable/bitmap with unscaled icon and fill the background with some color? 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 17):

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name);
icon.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
icon.draw(canvas);
```

You can use `icon.getIntrinsicHeight()` and `icon.getIntrinsicWidth()` to get the preferred size of the icon.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer :) I can't vote up your answer because i don't have enough reputation, but hopefully others will.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if you can. It will help other with the same problem.